# Resize custom menu item

Tags: android, customization, android-menu

I need help to re-size my current menu item. I created a custom menu with programmatically  added items in a `TableLayout`. This is my current menu:

[image: this is my current menu]

I need to change the height of the first menu. Now the problem is that when I change the height of the first menu item the entire menu changes its height. I want menu like this:

[image: i want menu like this]

Is there any way to re-size my current item?

```
public synchronized void show(View v) {
    mIsShowing = true;
    boolean isLandscape = false;
    int itemCount = mMenuItems.size();
    if (itemCount<1) return; //no menu items to show
    if (mPopupWindow != null) return; //already showing
    Display display = ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    if (display.getWidth() > display.getHeight()) isLandscape = true;
    View mView= mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_menu, null);
    mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(mView,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, false);
    mPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
    mPopupWindow.setWidth(display.getWidth());
    mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

    int divisor = mItemsPerLineInPortraitOrientation;
    if (isLandscape) divisor = mItemsPerLineInLandscapeOrientation;
    int remainder = 0;
    if (itemCount < divisor) {
        mRows = 1;
        remainder = itemCount;
    } else {
        mRows = (itemCount / divisor);
        remainder = itemCount % divisor;
        if (remainder != 0) mRows++;
    }
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)mView.findViewById(R.id.custom_menu_table);
    table.removeAllViews();

    for (int i=0; i < mRows; i++) {
        TableRow row = null;
        TextView tv = null;
        ImageView iv = null;

        row = new TableRow(mContext);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for (int j=0; j< divisor; j++) {
            if (i*divisor+j >= itemCount) break;
            final CustomMenuItem cmi = mMenuItems.get(i*divisor+j);
            View itemLayout = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_menu_item, null);
            if  (j==0)
            {
                itemLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.current_menu);
                itemLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            }

            tv = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.custom_menu_item_caption);
            tv.setText(cmi.getCaption());
            iv = (ImageView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.custom_menu_item_icon);
            iv.setImageResource(cmi.getImageResourceId());
            itemLayout.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                    mListener.MenuItemSelectedEvent(cmi);
                    if (mHideOnSelect) hide();
               }
            });
            row.addView(itemLayout);
        }
        table.addView(row);
    }
}
```

if i give background to entire row than result
[image]
if give background to layout(each menu item) by this line  itemLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
[image]

But i want look like this menu
[image]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do what you want would be to make the menu `TableLayout` a bit bigger than normal(it should be as tall as the selected menu height will be) and add some top padding or margin to any other menu item which isn't the current selected one. So one item will always be taller than all other items which will have a bit of space at the top.

Edit: Please use the proper `LayoutParams` especially when working with `TableLayout` and `TableRow`:

```
row = new TableRow(mContext);
row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
// ...
View itemLayout = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_menu_item, row, false);
```

Try to use margin instead of padding:

```
//...
for (int j=0; j< divisor; j++) {
   if (i*divisor+j >= itemCount) break;
   final CustomMenuItem cmi = mMenuItems.get(i*divisor+j);
   View itemLayout = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_menu_item, row, false);
   TableRow.Layoutparams lp = (TableRow.LayoutParams)itemLayout.getLayoutParams(); 
   if  (j==0) {
     lp.topMargin = 0; 
     itemLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.current_menu);
     itemLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
   } else {
     lp.topMargin = 12;
   }
   // ...
   itemLayout.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
             mListener.MenuItemSelectedEvent(cmi);
             if (mHideOnSelect) hide();
             TableRow parent = (TableRow) v.getParent();
             final int count = parent.getChildCount();
             for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                 final View child = parent.getChild(i);  
                 final TableRow.LayoutParams lp = (TableRow.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                 if (child == v) {
                      lp.topMargin = 0;
                 } else {
                      lp.topMargin = 12;
                 }       
             } 
       }
    });
```

Regarding space between cells, I don't see that, not even in your images.

Comment: thanks for replying! i tried add padding by setPadding() method. but problem can't solved.  is there any way to scale/resize view  because all item have individual view. which added last in tablelayout.

Comment: @BhavinChauhan *But problem can't be solved* - isn't very useful. Can you explain where did you called this, how does the menu look like(put the code in your question)?

Comment: thanks! i added code in question. i need another help. is there any way to remove space between 2 cells in tablelayout ?

Comment: thanks Luksprog for answer. now the margin concept work properly. but still i can't got proper solution. I added row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground); but can't got proper solution which i want. i need current menu item with overlapped.

Comment: @BhavinChauhan Proper solution meaning what? It doesn't look like it should? You don't end up with a menu item bigger than the other menu items? I don't see any overlapping in your images(maybe try providing a better image?)?

Comment: thanks! Luksprog for supporting and conversation. i uploaded image what i exactly need .